Nuxt3 / Storyblok full SSG
i'm currently building a blog that get it's content from Storyblok API.
i want my blog to be full static and for that i use the "npm run generate" that work almost as i want. There's one issue though that i can't figure out :
On the homepage, i display several block that represent some categories. For that, i use "useAsyncData", which works well for all of them (by working well, i mean i have no XHR requests on client side when my blog is generated).
here an example :
<script setup>
const storyblokApi = useStoryblokApi();
const { data: collabsPosts } = await useAsyncData("collabsPosts", async () => {
  try {
    const result = await storyblokApi.get("cdn/stories", {
      starts_with: "articles/",
      per_page: 5,
      sort_by: 'first_published_at:desc',
      resolve_relations: "post.tags",
    });
    return result.data.stories || [];
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching stories:', err);
    return [];
  }
});
</script>

My problem occurs when i want to display my articles. For their template (pages/articles/[slug].vue) i'm using "useAsyncStoryblok" as proposed on [https://nuxt.com/modules/storyblok][1] :
<script setup>
// Fetch slug from route params
const { slug } = useRoute().params;

const story = await useAsyncStoryblok(
  'articles/' + slug,
  {version: "publish", resolve_relations: "post.categories,post.related" }
);

</script>

<template>
  <StoryblokComponent v-if="story"
    :story="story"
    :blok="story.content"
    :name="story.name"
    :date="story.first_published_at"
    :author="story.content.author"
    :categories="story.content.categories"
    :related="story.content.related"
  />
</template>

but no matter what, it keeps fetching content on storyblok on client side when generated. Same happen with categories template, that also use "useAsyncStoryblok"
i've tried "useAsyncData" on the template but it's the same results.
i've made a quick preview here : https://preview-carreblanc-blog.netlify.app/ (don't mind the console error, and home breadcrumb is not working).
if you load the url, you'll see there is no request to storyblok API. But once you click an article, you'll see the request to storyblok API in the network tabs. What's even weird, is that if i load my article directly by url, there is no storyblok API call neither...
i'm a bit confused here and some help would be much appreciated :)
